# avoid adding duplicate items to a listview android

Tags: android, listview

Hi i have list view with some items from the database and when user enters the same items it should not add it to the list view but in my case it does. How to avoid this with a toast message saying that word already exists.please help me

i am populating the list from the DB and when adding new items it should compare the values in the db column if the value does not exist it can add otherwise error message should be shown. please correct this code

String sql = "Select text From MorseCodePresets WHERE text = "+etMorseCodeMessage.getText().toString();
                executeDBManagement(sql);

```
            Cursor c = getAllEntries("MorseCodePresets", null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                if(c.equals(sql)){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Word alredy exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                saveMorseCodeMessage();
            }
```

Comment: How do you populate the list view?

Comment: arraylist.. from the db and when i add new items it should compare the values in db if exists error message should be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this second if, `if(c.equals(sql))`, if the query returns a result, then the entered value already exists, and you can display the Toast message.

```
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
  // contains duplicate
} else {
  // new value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maintain an arraylist( or list or array) having all existing values and when there is any new entry, make a cross verification with iterations on list you made.
And store it accordingly

Answer (score -1):

While fetching data from the database you can add the **DISTINCT** keyword which will cause the query not to return duplicate values.

Comment: He has not said anything about databases.